# .NET 4.0 MSBuild.exe not recognizing web deploy arguments

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.0, webdeploy

I have .NET 4.0 installed on a build server, along with Web Deploy 1.1

I've opened up a command window to test the web deployment, but whenever I run it, the build succeeds, and no publish happens.

I try the exact same thing on my development machine, and the deploy fires, so I'm left wondering, why does msbuild not start the publish on my build server?

Here's the command I'm runnning

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe NerdDinner.sln /P:Configuration=Release  /P:DeployOnBuild=True  /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish  /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=http://someserver/MsDeployAgentService /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True  /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent  /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True  /P:UserName=user /P:Password=password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to reinstall .NET 4.0 on the box.

For some reason, after I reinstalled the framework, the web deploy starting working fine.

I'm still not sure what the problem was, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

On server, the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0 seemed to be corrupted. Pasted a local one with same subfolders and worked fine!